# Изменение структуры данных ответа в geosuggest yandex карт

Tags: php, mysql, yandex-maps-api

На сайте используется suggest-maps.yandex.ru/v1/suggest для получения подсказок и структуру которая приходит в ответе (results.0.address.component, component - это массив от страны до конечной точки) я сохраняю в БД себе для нужд сервиса.
Столкнулся с проблемой следующего характера, пример - раньше "AREA" приходили как "округ Краснодар" а вот недавно начали приходить "муниципальное образование Краснодар". Из-за чего появились дубли записей в БД. На сайте Яндекса ни где не нашел информации о том что произошли изменения и не повторится ли снова.

Comment: а вопрос, собственно, в чём состоит?

Comment: Сохранение себе копии базы Яндекса — это не то, что они предлагают. Используйте онлайн — будете получать всегда актуальные данные. А если при обновлении у них будет переименование чего угодно, отдельно они нигде это списками выкладывать не будут.